# What's the difference between unique/private/special?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between these sentences?

> 1- Komodo dragon is **unique to** Indonesia.
>  2- Komodo dragon is
> **private to** Indonesia.
>  3- Komodo dragon is **special to** Indonesia.

Comment: Unique, Private & Special are completely different words, so each one has a very different meaning, with little overlap.

Comment: #2 is completely non-idiomatic. #3 would normally be understood to mean *Indonesians have a [special] high regard for the Kimono dragon*.

Comment: so what about #1? and is it correct to put the preposition "to" after the word "unique"?

Comment: (1) is the only correct one, given that (as I understand) the Komodo dragon is found only in Indonesia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Komodo Dragon is unique to Indonesia.

This sentence highlights the fact that the species of Komodo Dragon (a specie of lizard) is found only in Indonesia or parts of Indonesia. The sentence is grammatically correct.

> Komodo Dragon is private to Indonesia.

The lizard is not a property to be claimed private or public by someone. It is highly non-idiomatic as pointed by @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica in the comments.

> Komodo Dragon is special to Indonesia.

*Special* is a synonym of *unique*, but doesn't mean it can be used inter-changeably with the word "unique".

The best alternative to sentence 1 would be:

> Komodo Dragon is **exclusive to** Indonesia.

Some references to meanings: [Unique](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=unique%20), [Special](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02niIXXMUjWUR-JdjsJmRgmeO-gxg:1600701417630&q=define%20special&forcedict=special&dictcorpus=en&expnd=1), [Private](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01v5HpxfDDbqjOIhA4eMafzzj-Fww%3A1600701949546&ei=_cVoX5uDIZud4-EP-8Oq8AM&q=private%20meaning&oq=private%20mean&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgkIIxAnEEYQ-QEyAggAMgcIABAUEIcCMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoFCAAQkQI6BQgAELEDUB5Y5AdgrA1oAHABeACAAcABiAGRB5IBAzAuNpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab), [Exclusive](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01IouhZGonWBoO570fiqeGsgqQgbw:1600701605888&q=define%20exclusive&forcedict=exclusive&dictcorpus=en&expnd=1)

> **Unique**: being the only one of its kind; unlike anything else.
>
> **Special**: belonging specifically to a particular person or place.
>
> **Private**: belonging to or for the use of one particular person or group of people only.
>
> **Exclusive**: restricted to the person, group, or area concerned.